# Force a connection from PHP to MySQL version 4

Tags: mysql, php

I am trying to connect a PHP application to a version 4 MySQL database.
Both are running on an internal network on different servers. There is no outside exposure.

I've tried using three MySQL connectors and all refuse to connect with a similar error:

```
Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 &amp; 4.0 servers is not supported
```

1. mysql_connect
2. MySQLi
3. PDO

Is there any way I can force this connection?

At the moment the only workaround I can think of (apart from upgrading the DB) is to use Perl and it's DBI/DBD::mysql library which doesn't complain about the database version.

Is there some ancient PHP mysql library laying around that I can perhaps use?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098554/connecting-to-old-mysql-servers

Comment: and look into `socat` to expose that domain socket over the network (which is likely necessary in that situation).